# oTable.fnFilter is not working

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to provide search in `thead` of datatables and implement search in it...but it is not working...

```
$("#listings_row thead input").keyup( function () {
    oTable.fnFilter( this.value, $(this).attr('id') );
} );

<thead style="background:none;border:none;" id="searchbox">
    <tr class="search_box">
        <th><input type="text" style="height:16px;" name="search_engine" value="Search engines"   class="search_init" id="1" /></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/methew/u9654/3/

only this line is not working properly ...oTable.fnFilter( this.value, $(this).attr('id') );

Comment: http://aboutshafiq.com/crm/companylist.php

Comment: it works just fine if you include the needed hs/css files http://jsfiddle.net/caAde/ (I know it looks ugly the html code too - but its just to show you that all works...)

Comment: search on each cloumn is still not working properly,please check in your jsfiddle

Comment: only this line is not working properly ...oTable.fnFilter( this.value, $(this).attr('id') );

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pay Attention to the `id`s of your `<input` it starts from *1* , while it should start from *5*

You are using the values of `id` to do the sort of the column ... so since your ids start from 1 you are applying the filters to the wrong columns

[Here a jsfiddle - quick and dirty working version](http://jsfiddle.net/caAde/3/)